# How to get come back to SaveUserDetails.html file after showing success.jsp for some time interval (like 2 seconds)?

Tags: jsp

I have a HTML Page (SaveUserDetails.html) which saves user details with help of a servlet.
 I am showing Success.jsp file to the User once he has saved the details successfully.
 I am using response.sendRedirect("Success.jsp"); for re-directing to success page
 But the problem is I want Success.jsp to be shown for a particular interval of time.

Can anyone help me to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what u are tryin to say exactly, looks like u solved the problem urself ... in anycase i misunderstood, and u want it to redirect to another page after success.jsp then u can use javascript to get it done.

```
function redirectFunction(){
window.location = "../someOtherJsp" }
```

for the time delay you can use the SetTimeOut

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout('redirectFunction()', 2000)">
```

should work ...